# summary and restricted output from fdisk in ubuntu bionic beaver

Tags: 18.04, fdisk

I don't know if this is a hardware or software issue, but on my Dell XPS, running 18.04, when I type `sudo fdisk -l` I get all sorts of garbage that I don't want to see of the form

```
 Disk /dev/loop21: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I don't know what these /dev/loop devices are and certainly don't want to see any information about them.     All I care about is my actual disks,
and I'd like to see a summary that can fit onto one page.

I can eliminate the `/dev/loop` garbage by the call `sudo fdisk -l /dev/[nv]* /dev/sd*`   but this command still produces way more information than I need.

This kind of output---which is more or less what 16.04 used to produce---would be ideal if there were some way of filtering out all of the extraneous garbage.    That is, it just lists the available file systems and any partitions that are on them.

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors

Device               Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1        2048    1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2     1024000    1228799    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3     1228800    1261567     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4     1261568  158547967 157286400    75G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5   158547968  327999487 169451520  80.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6   327999488 1284618239 956618752 456.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7  1284618240 1835775999 551157760 262.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8  1835776000 1835778047      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p9  1835778048 1967998975 132220928    63G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p10 1967998976 2000408575  32409600  15.5G Linux swap



Disk /dev/sda: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Disk /dev/sdb1: 30 GiB, 32212140032 bytes, 62914336 sectors
```

Perhaps there's an alternative to fdisk that's more customizable?  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You may want to try `parted -l`.

Comment: You can create an **alias** to customize the output of `fdisk` (or `parted` or `lsblk` ...). I often use `sudo lsblk -fm` in a wide terminal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `lsdrv` (list drive) which is an alias of `lsblk ...` setup in my `~/.bashrc` file.

```
$ lsdrv
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL            MOUNTPOINT   SIZE MODEL
sr0                                              1024M DVD+/-RW DW316  
sda                                             931.5G HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda4       ntfs   WINRETOOLS                    450M 
├─sda2                                            128M 
├─sda5       ntfs   Image                        11.4G 
├─sda3       ntfs   HGST_Win10       /mnt/d       919G 
└─sda1       vfat   ESP                           500M 
nvme0n1                                           477G Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB            
├─nvme0n1p5  ntfs                                 858M 
├─nvme0n1p3                                        16M 
├─nvme0n1p1  ntfs                                 450M 
├─nvme0n1p8  ntfs   Shared_WSL+Linux /mnt/e         9G 
├─nvme0n1p6  ext4   New_Ubuntu_16.04 /           23.7G 
├─nvme0n1p4  ntfs   NVMe_Win10       /mnt/c     363.2G 
├─nvme0n1p10 ext4   Ubuntu_18.04     /mnt/clone  27.2G 
├─nvme0n1p2  vfat                    /boot/efi     99M 
├─nvme0n1p9  swap                    [SWAP]       7.9G 
└─nvme0n1p7  ext4   Old_Ubuntu_16.04 /mnt/old    44.6G
```

The alias selects the important fields I want to see that fit on a regular screen without line wrapping:

```
$ alias lsdrv
alias lsdrv='lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL | grep -v loop'
```

Comment: Perfect thanks!     I just had to add a `| grep -v loop` to your alias to get rid of all of the extraneous `loop` partitions, whatever they were

Comment: @LeoSimon I added your comment to the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From `man fdisk`:

```
Note that partx(8) provides a rich interface for scripts to print disk layouts,  fdisk  is
       mostly  designed  for  humans.   Backward  compatibility  in  the  output  of fdisk is not
       guaranteed.  The input (the commands) should always be backward compatible.
```